# External email with exceeded file size limit - no NDR

Tags: exchange-2010

Someone from outside of the company has emailed a user inside the company with a file size at about 19MB. Our limit was 15MB however they did not receive an NDR stating their file size was too big. What can cause them not to receive this NDR from our exchange 2010 server?

Cheers.

Comment: What have you tested so far? Have you tried to send a large attachment, or are you relying on 3rd party information? Is it possible you have disabled NDR in your org?

Comment: I've tried testing it by sending a file that big however none of my own personal accounts will let me attach a file that big. NDR is not disabled as other NDR's not related are sent out, is it possible this specific one is disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the message tracking logs on your Exchange server to see for sure if the NDR is being sent out. Their side's spam blocker might decide to drop inbound NDRs or deliver them to a Junk folder.

To check the message tracking logs in Exchange 2010 see here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/messaging_with_communications/archive/2011/04/22/how-to-track-message-in-exchange-2003-2007-2010.aspx

Comment: It does not appear that an NDR was sent from Exchange in the message log. Other NDR were sent out but nothing pertaining to a size limit.

Comment: I'm thinking its possible that a message may not have even been sent to us from the sender with the large file size, message tracking didn't pick anything up, but how can I know for sure?

Comment: If message tracking doesn't show anything coming in and you don't have an email gateway or service upstream from your Exchange server that you can check, then it most likely never left their mail server(s).  You would have to get with their IT dept. though to know for certain what their own restrictions are or to have them trace the email from the sending side and see how far it got.